# C# EF6 Code First TPH - Navigation properties to two entities who inhrerits the same entity using annotations

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, inheritance

I have a question regarding EF6. Let's say I have an abstract base class that looks like this:

```
[Table("Persons")]
public abstract class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("Group")]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true), MaxLength(150)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true), MaxLength(150)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then there are two entities that inherit `Person`:

```
[Table("Persons")]
public class Teacher : Person
{
    [Required]
    public int ExpirienceInYears { get; set; }
}

[Table("Persons")]
public class Student : Person
{
    [Required]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

That is all fine here for me. We have some TPH and this is why we got a Discriminator column. OK, fine but my problem are the navigation properties in the table `Groups` which actually look like this:

```
[Table("Groups")]
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true), MaxLength(150)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

It seems like the navigation properties are responsible for the generation of two columns in the Table Persons that are Named: `Group_Id` and `Group_Id1` which are always empty. I don't need this columns, because in this table there is already a column `GroupId` with points to `Groups`. Also the navigation properties are not working, so I think I am doing something wrong.

The table `Persons` looks like:

```
Id |  GroupId | FirstName | LastName | ExpirienceInYears | Age | Discriminator | Group_Id | Group_Id1
```

but I want this table to look like:

```
Id |  GroupId | FirstName | LastName | ExpirienceInYears | Age | Discriminator
```

If I remove the navigation properties everything is OK, but I would love to keep them because they are really handy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are configuring two one-to-many relationships, one between `Teacher` and `Group` and the another one between `Student` and `Group`, that's way you have two additional FK columns (`Group_Id` and `Group_Id1`) in your `Persons` table. To achieve what you want you need to establish just one relationship between `Person` and `Group` this way:

```
[Table("Persons")]
public abstract class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...
    [ForeignKey("Group")]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}

[Table("Groups")]
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //...
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }    
}
```

Then, if you need to work with students of an specific group you can filter them this way:

```
var group=db.Groups.Find(1);//search an specific group
var students=group.Persons.OfType<Student>();// get all the students of that group
```